# Linear map sending the standard basis elements {$e_i$} of $\mathbb{R}^m$ to the linear functional basis {$d_i$} of $T_a\mathbb{R}^m$.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Hadamard's Lemma says that, for $a \in \mathbb{R}^m$, every $f \in C^{\infty}_a(\mathbb{R}^m)$ has the form

$$f(x)=f(a)+\sum^{m}_{i=1}(x_i-a_i)g_i(x)$$

where $g_i(x) \in C^{\infty}_{a}(\mathbb{R}^m)$. We then have that $g_i(a)=\frac{df}{dx_i}(a)$. For each $i$, we have $d_i \in T_a\mathbb{R}^m$ defined by $$d_i . f = \frac{df}{dx_i}(a)$$ for all $f \in C^{\infty}_a(\mathbb{R}^m)$.

I understand why $d_i \in T_a\mathbb{R}^m$ (they are linear functionals on $\mathcal{G}_a(\mathbb{R}^m)$ and satisfy the Leibniz condition), but why does the above give rise to a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $T_a\mathbb{R}^m$ which maps the standard basis {$e_i$} of $\mathbb{R}^m$ to the basis {$d_i$} of $T_a\mathbb{R}^m$?

{$d_i$} are linear functionals, which act on $f$, not the other way around, so how can we ever find a map taking {$d_i$} and returning a vector {$e_i$}?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you mention orthogonality. Given a vector space $V$ and $m$ vectors $v_1, \dots, v_m \in V$, there always exists a unique linear map $f : \mathbb{R}^m \to V$ such that $f(e_i) = v_i$. You can just define it by $f(x_1, \dots, x_m) = x_1 v_1 + \dots + x_m v_m$. No conditions. It's just linear algebra, nothing fancy. Does this answer your question or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi thanks a lot for the reply. Yes this clarifies things. I was visualising it wrong before.